# My iptables works the opposite from what I wanted

Tags: iptables

I have this set of `iptables` rules ...

```
$ sudo iptables -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 5/min bu
REJECT     tcp  --  192.168.1.134        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 reject-w

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

... the above blocks 192.168.1.134 but it does not log attempts from 192.168.1.134.  Instead connections from other clients are logged.  I just want to log the dropped packets.
What I want to do is log all dropped packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the existing `LOG` rule and replace it with a rule to only log packets matching `--dport 22`.  That will match the same packets that will be rejected by the `REJECT` rule

```
iptables -D INPUT 1  # Deletes rule 1 on INPUT chain
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.134 --dport 22 -j LOG
```

Comment: Thanks Creek!  That works.  Next I would want to figure out how to log all dropped packets.  Is there a simple catch all iptables command I could issue or would I have to understand the rules that are already defined?

Comment: @RedCricket there's a couple ways you can do it.  Start a new question for it so the answer doesn't get lost in these comments